# What's the best way to have all different view classes to implement the same method in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I am creating one of my first Objective-C apps. I have a bunch of UIViews and Other views such as MapView and so forth.

In my Model I have a method called register that all views, well, register with. They are all put in a NSMutableArray in the model. Any time the model has updated data I run a for loop over the array of "views" and I would like all views no matter there type to implement a method called "update" that can be called from the model on each view.

Being that a view could be a UIView or of any other type I'm not really sure what the Objective-c way is of doing this is.

I'd really like to be able to do something like the following but I know this is not correct.

```
for(NSInteger i=0; i<[_views count]; i++)
{
    NSObject *view = [_views objectAtIndex:i];
    [view update:data];

}
```

Comment: Just a note about the answers, protocols in Objective C are similar to interafces in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a protocol:

```
@protocol IUpdateable <NSObject>
@required
-(void)update:(id)data;
@end
```

Then in your view class implement the protocol...

```
@interface SomeView : UIView <IUpdateable>
@end;

@implementation SomeView
-(void)update:(id)data
{
    //Do something with data
}
@end;
```

Then you can call your methods in one fell swoop assuming your `_views` array contains a collection of `IUpdateable` views...

```
[_views makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(update:) withObject:someData];
```

Reference: [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html), [Working with Protocols](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html)

Comment: +1 because I wasn't aware of `makeObjectsPerformSelector`. How embarrassing.

Comment: can I pass more than one argument using makeObjectsPreformSelector or is withObject the best way ? I'm thinking I will pass an object that has a data type value and the actual data that way each view can inspect the update "type" so that it can decide if it's interested in the data being sent to it.

Comment: One object only, but the object can be as complex as you want it

Comment: Some more food for thought - you can use `NSNotificationCenter` to post a notification with an object and any object listening for the notification can act on it. This is quite useful if, say, your app allows users to choose a theme. User changes theme, you send a notification, then every single object that listens to said notification can update themselves.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to do the same thing the Cocoa delegates do. Define a formal protocol with the `update` method, and make all your `UIView` classes (or any other classes that you want to be registerable with the model) adopt that protocol.

Define the protocol:

```
@protocol Updateable <NSObject>
@required
- (void) update: (id)data;
@end
```

Adopt the protocol:

```
@interface MyView : UIView <Updateable>
- (void) update: (id)data;
...
@end;
```